# What is the Pythonic Way of doing a subset in-place update to a Pandas Dataframe (and Numpy)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Assume 'data' is a Pandas DataFrame where 'rows' are all rows, and 'cols' is some number less than or equal to the actual number of columns. I have the following code which works fine to multiply all data in that space by 'scale'. I'm specifically avoiding using column names, I need to use column indexes.

```
rows = len(data.index)
for row in range(0,rows):
    for col in range (0, cols):
        data.iat[row,col] = data.iat[row,col] * scale
```

However as you can see this is not Python-like or Pandas-like. What is the Python/Pandas way? Assume all rows will be affected, but only columns from the 0th to cols-1. For example if the dataframe is 5x4 but cols=3, then only columns 0,1,2 will be updated (in all rows). In other words, if this is my dataframe:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

and scale is 10 and cols is 3 then the result should be:

```
10 20 30 4
10 20 30 4
10 20 30 4
10 20 30 4
10 20 30 4
```

**Also, same question/answer please for a Numpy array.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want: It uses the iloc method to change the values of the columns. basic idea of iloc is to use the index numbers for rows and columns. You can read more about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-integer) :

```
df.iloc[:,0:3] = df.iloc[:,0:3].mul(10)

    0   1   2   3
0   10  20  30  4
1   10  20  30  4
2   10  20  30  4
3   10  20  30  4
4   10  20  30  4
```

Another option, which is more succinct is offered by Jon Clement:

```
df.iloc[:,:-1] *= 10
```

This is simpler, less code, and still understandable. Thanks Jon!

Comment: You can do it inplace and `-1` if you just want everything except the last... eg: `df.iloc[:, :-1] *= 10`

Comment: @sammywemmy Both answers work (thank you, both are what I was looking for), but both also produce a warning, "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame." I understand the warning, its because of chain indexing, and I know it still works regardless of the warning, but any ideas how to avoid the warning?

Comment: @greco.roamin is it the same for both approaches? What pandas version are you using and does `df.dtypes` show all int64s?

Comment: you could use the copy() method ... df.copy()... hopefully, this is not coming from an action you had done previously in your code

Comment: @JonClements Pandas version 0.25.3. The DataFrame is all floats and I'm multiplying by an integer or float (same warning in both cases)

Comment: @sammywemmy it is definitely not coming from a previous action, but that's a valid point. I isolated this code to be the only code in the application (just to make sure). Also, the issue is well documented as a chain indexing warning, I just don't see how to avoid it in this case.

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks for the help. Although I don't see how to get around the chain warning, you did answer with what I was looking for, so I'm marking it accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

use dataframe slicing

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,1], 'b': [2,2,2,2,2], 'c': [3,3,3,3,3], 'd': [4,4,4,4,4]})                                                                 

>>> df                                                                                                                                              
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  1  2  3  4
2  1  2  3  4
3  1  2  3  4
4  1  2  3  4

>>> df.loc[:, 'a':'c'] = df.loc[:, 'a':'c'] * 10
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I'm specifically avoiding using column names, I need to use column indexes. I updated the question to reflect that since it wasn't clear.